# Convert Option[Int] to String and back to Option[Int]

Tags: scala

I have an API which converts an Option[Int] to a String. I want to convert this back to an Option[Int]. What's the best way of doing this in Scala?

```
val x = Some(1)
val y = x.toString
val z: Option[Int] = ???  // Expected value is Some(1) from y
```

Comment: Why did you convert it to a String in the first place? Are you trying to serializate and deserializate some data? If so, you may be better using some standard formats than plain strings.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Agreed, string is not ideal in this case. I am writing a deserializer but I don't have any control over how the data is being serialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala 2.13

```
y match { 
  case s"Some($x)" => x.toIntOption
  case _ => None
}
```

In Scala 2.12

```
val someInt = """Some\((\d+)\)""".r
y match { 
  case someInt(x) => Try(x.toInt).toOption
  case _ => None
}
```